# Passing raw JSONObject in POST request in Volley

Tags: android, android-volley

I am using Volley android to POST request to my webservice. Below is the format which I want to post in Body.

```
//      {
//          "cust_id": "3",
//          "amount": "150",
//          "items": [
//               {"itemid":"2",
//                "qty":"4"},
//               {"itemid":"5",
//                "qty":"3"},
//              {"itemid":"1",
//                "qty":"5"}
//          ]
//      }
```

items(JSONArray) list is variable. I am using below to pass params

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();


    for (MenuItem m:orderedList) {
        JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject();
        obj1.put("itemid", m.getImgid());
        obj1.put("qty", m.getQty());
        jsonArray.put(obj1);
    }
    JSONObject obj2 = new JSONObject();
    obj2.put("cust_id",cust_id);
    obj2.put("amount",totamt);
    obj2.put("items",jsonArray);
    Log.d("Volley request order",obj2.toString());
    JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Config.ORDER_URL, obj2, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                VolleyLog.v("Response is:%n %s", response.toString(4));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.e("Error is: ", error.getMessage());
        }
    });

    // Adding request to request queue
    LifeCycle.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req, tag_json_obj);
```

My Code is working, My Question how do I check complete request body and header as we do in OkHTTp Interceptor.

Comment: Using String cut and append is a bad idea to make Json.

Comment: create json object of that data and pass that object in request.

Comment: thanks, I remove the string append and create JSONObject. updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Your making Json is so sick! Don't use String cut and append to make Json.
Anyway, if you want to know what was  you make, you can use this code below

```
JsonObject json = JsonObject(params);
Log.i("json", json.toString());
```

Comment: @CoDFather give an explain, CoD. He want to know what he post in body, so this is what he post.

Comment: your answer is incomplete. it will only finish when you answer to his question. He wanted to know whether request body is send or not?